# Vue3 How to get the DOM element in Suspense

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-suspense

I need to get the reference of DOM Element in Suspense #default when the resolve event of the Suspense has emitted.

```
<script setup>
  function test(e){
      console.log(e) // Expected to get <p> element ref
    }
</script>

<template>
  <Suspense @resolve="test">
    <template #default>
      <p class="text">Some async component</p>
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      Loading...
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you have problems with using a regular template ref?

Comment: I have more than 1 async component with same class and I need to get their references seperately when they mount

Comment: A class is irrelevant, you aren't supposed to get an element by DOM selector. See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs